# When it is ok to use strong references in android and does this code leak?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-lifecycle

It is not clear to me when is best to use `WeakReference` to avoid memory leaks in android. Example:
Code in fragment:

```
containerView.setDataForDisplay(customer, new CustomListener() {    
      @Override  
      public void buttonClicked(@NonNull Customer customer) {  
                if(handler != null) {
                    handler.buttonClickedForCustomer(customer);  
                }  
            }  
        });
```

The code inside the custom `LinearLayout`

```
public void setDataForDisplay(List<Customer> customer, CustomListener listener) {  
 // view setup code  

 someView.setOnClickListener( v -> {  
    if(listener != null) {  
       listener.buttonClicked(v.getTag());  
    }  
 });
}
```

The anonymous class `CustomListener` has a reference to the containing fragment's `this`.
That anonymous class is passed as a listener to a containing view which in turn does a callback eventually.

My question is does this lead to a memory leak?
Should the `listener` be hold somehow in a `WeakReference`? How do we decide when it is ok to have a strong reference vs a weak reference?

Comment: well, it's all about dependency and scenario, let's take a  common example of async task, which does require a context doing some task in the background, now suppose before the task completion, you closed the host activity. Now in async's background task is over and will look for context but context is not there since host activity we closed it. That kind of scenario where we use a weak ref to hold the data.

Comment: @notTdar:That case assumes a static reference to the async task right? Because if it was an instance variable of the activity would there be a problem?

Comment: @Jim did you find any solution, how did you handle this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't a memory leak.

A simplified reference graph might look something like this:

[image: references graph]

True, the graph does contain a circular reference, but the garbage collector is perfectly capable of detecting & addressing that situation. The entire graph would be GC'd after the system loses its reference to the `Fragment`, which is generally going to be right around the time it's dismissed from the screen.

I can't contrive a situation where a `WeakReference` would be *needed* to prevent a memory leak. (I'm not saying they don't exist, I just can't come up with one.)

I see `WeakReferences` as a tool for advanced memory management tasks, of the kind that rarely pops up in general application development. Like: Managing a collection of large items, where it's *OK* if some of them get GC'd (as memory runs out), but you'd *rather* keep them in RAM.

IOW: Don't keep around any references you don't need, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Modern JVM has a very powerful garbage collector. It manages to collect even cyclic references, by detecting objects that are completely isolated form gc roots. You can read more on this topic here:
[How Garbage Collection Really Works](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/)

By using weak references. however, you can speed up the work of the gc, because this references are to be collected immediately after all strong references on this object are gone.